# Use sed command to check if a particular word exists, if not, add the word

Tags: bash, sed

The sed command below enables me to convert all the commas into the string `and`:

`markers=$(echo generic,daily,nightly | sed -e "s/,/ and /g")`

`echo $markers` will result in:

`generic and daily and nightly`

Now I would like to achieve the following:

If the word `nightly` is not present in the `$markers` it should add the string `and not nightly` to `$markers` string

Is that possible to achieve it with `sed`?

Comment: `sed -e "s/,/ and /g" -e "/nightly/!s/$/, not nightly/"`?

Comment: The replacement string of the second command shall probably be `and not nightly` instead of `, not nightly`. Or the two commands swapped.

Comment: Please provide an example test case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 1. "generic,daily,nightly,weekly,monthly" 2. "generic,daily,weekly,monthly"

Comment: What should be the result for `generic,daily,weekly,monthly`? Do you need to account for a whole word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For `generic,daily,weekly,monthly` the result should be `generic and daily and weekly and monthly and not nightly` (because `nightly` is not present there). For `generic,daily,nightly,weekly,monthly` the result should be `generic and daily and nightly and weekly and monthly` (because `nightly` is  present there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
#!/bin/bash

s='generic,daily,weekly,monthly
generic,daily,nightly,weekly,monthly'
markers=$(echo "$s" | sed -e "s/,/ and /g" -e "/nightly/!s/$/ and not nightly/")
echo "$markers"
```

Output:

```
generic and daily and weekly and monthly and not nightly
generic and daily and nightly and weekly and monthly
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/rS8EFq). The `/nightly/!s/$/ and not nightly/` does the following:

- `/nightly/!` - skip a line if it contains `nightly`, else
- `s/$/ and not nightly/` - replace end of string with  `and not nightly`.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew thanks a lot for your help!